# How do you show search text in vscode with vim-extension?

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, vim

With vim, you view what you type when you do a search function with "/" in the console.
In vscode with vim-extension, you don't see what you type when you do "/", only the characters is hightlighting with colour.
Is it possible to have a box to view what you are typing with search function ?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The vim extension (VSCodeVim) displays the search bar in the lower left corner.

Comment: Thanks, the statusbar was disabled.